# Random pictures in Android studio

Tags: android

I hope you enlight me with this, I want to make an activity which it has any number of pictures which a user can choose and a button to make random picking ,also I'm as developer can add more pictures in future.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962816/get-random-images-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
private static final Random random = new Random();
private static final Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.image0, R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};

public void changeImageResource() {
    int i = random.nextInt(5);
    findViewById(R.id.background).setBackgroundResource(mImageIds[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that helps me a lot, why am I getting a -votes ?! as long as that helps me !!